# What should be done about these similar Skyrim questions that ask if certain NPCs are available for marriage?

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates

Seems to me that the later questions of the following should be closed as duplicates of the oldest one. Should they be closed? What should be done about these questions?

- [How can I determine if an NPC is available for marriage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35438/how-can-i-determine-if-an-npc-is-available-for-marriage) (oldest question)
- [Can Saadia be married?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42442/can-saadia-be-married)
- [Are any of the eligible bachelorettes Bards?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43053/are-any-of-the-eligible-bachelorettes-bards)
- [Can you marry Serana in Skyrim: Dawnguard?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77621/can-you-marry-serana-in-skyrim-dawnguard)
- [Can I marry Carlotta Valentia in Skyrim and if so, how?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85827/can-i-marry-carlotta-valentia-in-skyrim-and-if-so-how)
- [Is there a wood elf wife that you can marry?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225350/is-there-a-wood-elf-wife-that-you-can-marry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that they should be closed as duplicates of [How can I determine if an NPC is available for marriage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35438/how-can-i-determine-if-an-npc-is-available-for-marriage) since that question has the broadest scope and answers each of the other ones by telling people how to determine if an NPC is eligible.